# Populating second Table View with respect to selection made on first

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am new to xcode and Objective-C programming and need some help.

I am looking to create a basic program for the ios that uses array of data and 2 UITableViews in one single view. I want the second UITableView to be populated by an array which is based on the selection made in first Table.
I have an array of arrays for the second table. But can't understand how to put array at index 0 when data at index 0 is selected in first table.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [technologyData count];


}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    // Change UITableViewCellStyle
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (tableView == technologyTable)
{

[[cell textLabel] setText:[technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} 

if (tableView == experienceTable)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [experienceTable reloadData];
}
return cell ;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == technologyTable)
{
    experienceTable = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    selectTechnology.text = [technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.technologyList.hidden = YES;

}
if(tableView == experienceTable)
{
    self.experienceList.hidden = YES;
    selectExperience.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question, you can use one set of delegate methods in one view controller to control both tables.

You first create a property or IVAR of type UITableView for both tables and connect them to their respected tables in IB.

Then in any delegate methods (check to see what table is calling that particular method (ex):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (tableView == table1) {

   self.arrayIndex = indexPath.row;
   [table2 reloadData];

 } else if (tableView == table2) {

  //Secondary task

 } else {/* If necessary */}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (tableView == table1) {
     //Configure the top array as you need

     } else if (tableView == table2) {

      if(self.arrayIndex) {
        [arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:self.arrayIndex [subArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       } else {
        //figure something out
       }

     } else {/* If necessary */}

    }

}
```

If you want some help with code, post some.

Comment: what will be the syntax for cell.textlabel.text for second table.

Comment: When I select the first row of table1 then I get respected data in table 2 but when I select second row in table 1. It shows error index "1 beyond bounds"

Comment: That message happens when you are accessing an object that doesn't exist in an array. What that message tells me is either a) The array doesn't have an object at index 1 or b) you didn't properly allocate and initialize the array and so you are calling upon a nil array at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Find the target array that you want the second tableview to fill using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from `UITableViewDelegate`. After that reload the second tableview. That should get your problem solved.

Comment: Can u give me any sample code to show that. I have tried doing that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. but the didn't help.

Comment: There is a simple solution to what you are achieving. Define your target array. On your did select row method, set the target array from the dictionary, I guess that is where it is coming from. In the end, populate the second tableview from the target array. In this way every time you select a row, your target array is changed and all you have to do is reload that tableview. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: When I select the first row of table1 then I get respected data in table 2 but when I select second row in table 1. It shows error index "1 beyond bounds". I have edited the code. Please check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Tell me your id and I can provide you with a sample code that I had written a while ago. I am sure it will help you.

Comment: surbhit.thanvi@gmail.com thnx a lot

Comment: check you email and you should be able to find the code there.

Answer (score 0):

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`, you reload the table data like `[tbl reloadData]` by passing the targeted array.

Comment: should I make two different classes because of two table views in single view. Because in method didSelectRowAtIndexPath two table will be processed.

Comment: No need of doing this, use single class only. Take two tables & check the table name in delegate methods of table. And on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method reload the table. It definitely solves your problem.

Comment: When I select the first row of table1 then I get respected data in table 2 but when I select second row in table 1. It shows error index "1 beyond bounds". I have edited the code. Please check what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

In **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tv == table1) {
      arrForSecondTable = [arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [table2 reloadData];
    }
    else if (tv == table2) {
         // Do Something
     }
     else { // Do Something}
}
```

Comment: Also you haven't mentioned where to put cel.textlabel.text for second tabel.

Comment: When I select the first row of table1 then I get respected data in table 2 but when I select second row in table 1. It shows error index "1 beyond bounds". I have edited the code. Please check what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

As i observe in your code the problem is with this method :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [technologyData count];
}
```

You should check a condition in this method like this :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if(tableView == table1)
      return [technologyData count];
  else
      return [experience count];
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Just put a breakpoint at the line

```
experienceTable = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
and
selectExperience.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and debug it. I'm quite sure, you find the reason of crash.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know the application is crashing at line 'experienceTable = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];'  but don't know why

Comment: Just because you are assigning a array to a tableView (experienceTable) which is impossible.
because this line '[[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];' gives you a object that is not a TableView for sure.
 Make this line comment and run the app.

Comment: it is giving bad excess in method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" line " cell.textLabel.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
"

Comment: Just modify this line like this :
" cell.textLabel.text = [experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; "

Comment: here experience is an array of arrays having two arrays inside..... array1 and array2. And these two arrays contain different data.